# Action script error while running flex web application in IE. Error #2044

Tags: internet-explorer, flex4, adobe, flexbuilder

Error statement: An error has occurred in the script on this page. Line 110 char 446 Error: expected ':' code 0 URL http://clkads.com/adServe/static/btgen-ie-im3.html?tid=SWIM06
Do you want to continue running script on this page?
This error is shown for all the web applications. I am using flex builder 4.6
please help

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with your HTML template file in your project. I don't know if I would classify that as an actionscript error though. If the error isn't there I am at a loss. If you dont find it in there, track down what line 110 char 446 (and everything around it) and post it back.